# NSZombiEnabled settings

Tags: objective-c, nszombieenabled

I am trying to check NSZombieEnabled is working in my code. 
I've the following settings :

[image]

[image]

[image]

and I've the following code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
NSString *string = nil;
    [string release];
    string = @"abc";
```

but, there is no error generated. there is no notification from NSZombie as well. Should I do some more settings. Please help me, cause I've a lib that I've imported and there is a EXC_BAD_ACCESS with code 13 happening, and I am not able to get to the error cause.

The stack and the console looks like this
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your settings are correct, but your code does not create any zombies. A zombie is an object which has been freed, but is re-used. Something like this will create a zombie:

```
NSString* string = [NSString stringWithString:@"abc"];
[string release];
[string length];
```

In this example, the string is released, and then you attempt to use it by calling its `length` method.

In the case of your library, what does the stack look like when it gives you the EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Comment: Thanks for explaining the concept. I tried to generate a zombie, like you suggested, but still there is no error/message in the log. The code simply runs through to the next step without any warning/error/message. As for the library, I have added the details in the EDIT.